# How to remove everything after two different punctuations

Tags: regex, r

Consider

```
temp <- c("12/30 - 1/5", "4/21-4/27")
##[1] "12/30 - 1/5" "4/21-4/27"
```

I need

```
##[1] "12/30"     "4/21"
```

while I know how to produce each one of them separately

```
gsub(" .*", "", temp)
##[1] "12/30"     "4/21-4/27"

gsub("-.*", "", temp)
##[1] "12/30 " "4/21"
```

How can I combine them into one expression?

Comment: There is no need to escape either the space or the dash, by the way.

Comment: Oh, right (and good), but that's not what I meant. I meant that `gsub(" .*", "", temp)` and `gsub("-.*", "", temp)` would have been correct as well. The backslashes are unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) are there for:

```
> gsub("[ -].*", "", temp)
[1] "12/30" "4/21"
```

One caveat: In a character class, the dash takes on a special meaning unless it's in the first or last position of the class: It then denotes a range (as in `[0-9]` which matches any digit between `0` and `9`. If you wanted to match only `0`, `9` or a literal `-`, you would have to use `[09-]`). In the current regex, that's not an issue because there only are two characters inside the class. But when you start expanding the class (adding new characters), make sure you keep the dash at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably OR the regexps together, but I personally find that hard to read. Easier to just apply one `gsub` after the other:

```
> gsub("\\-.*", "",gsub("\\ .*", "", temp))
[1] "12/30" "4/21"
```

Comment: I actually tried to implement `|`, but couldn't find the right syntax. Your solution is what I'm doing already :)